# SQL issue - account permission system

Tags: sql

I am trying to make advanced permission system for accounts

1. Account can have a permission (directly) via `"account_permission"` table
2. Account can be a part of a group which can have a permission -> `"account_group"` and `"permission_group"` table (should called group_permission?)

### issue

I need to write SQL Select command that will returns all permissions associated with account (included group permission) in which is account member of

I have working example but im pretty sure it is not a best performance practice... and a "account_id" is duplicated in my example

```sql
    SELECT
      t1.*
    FROM
      permission AS t1
      LEFT JOIN
        account_permission AS t2
        ON t1.id = t2.permission_id
      LEFT JOIN
        permission_group AS t3
        ON t1.id = t3.permission_id
    WHERE
      t2.account_id = 'a518f2fb-7e46-4c0c-9428-c87eac6674e8'
      OR t3.group_id IN
      (
        SELECT
          group_id
        FROM
          account_group
        WHERE
          account_id = 'a518f2fb-7e46-4c0c-9428-c87eac6674e8'
      );
```

#### Database diagram

[image]

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code could also produce duplicates.  I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM permission p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM account_permission ap
              WHERE ap.permission_id = p.id AND
                    ap.account_id = 'a518f2fb-7e46-4c0c-9428-c87eac6674e8'
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM permission_group pg JOIN
                   account_group ag
                   ON pg.group_id = ag.group_id
              WHERE pg.permission_id = p.id AND
                    ag.account_id = 'a518f2fb-7e46-4c0c-9428-c87eac6674e8'
             );
```

This version cannot return duplicates (well, at least duplicates due to `join`s; I suppose `permissions` could have duplicates).

Then for performance, you want the following indexes:

- `account_perimission(permission_id, account_id)`
- `permission_group(permission_id, group_id)`
- `account_group(group_id, account_id)`

Comment: what about using "DISTINCT" to unify duplicates?

Comment: @Altaula . . . That just adds unnecessary overhead to the query.